# Error SENDING POST in rails and HTTPPARTY semantic error my request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, hash

this is my error when I lanunched my method {"errors"=>{"users"=>["Missing data for required field."]}, "msg"=>"The request was well-formed but was unable to be followed due to semantic errors."}

```
class BookingNotifier
include HTTParty
def initialize(booking_id)
  @booking = Booking.find booking_id
  @venue = @booking.event.service.venue
  @body = { "users" => [] }
  @headers = {
      "Accept" => "application/json",
      "Authorization" => "ENV_KEY",
      "Content-Type" => "application/json"
  }
end

def send_venue_notification
  venues_objects = []
    if @venue.notifications_enabled
      venues_objects << { "cellphone" => @booking.event.service.venue.phone,
                          "country_code" => "+57",
                          "user_session_keys" => [{ "key" => "Nombre",   "value" => @booking.profile.name },
                                                  { "key" => "Centro",   "value" => @booking.event.service.venue.name },
                                                  { "key" => "Cupos",    "value" =>  @booking.quantity },
                                                  { "key" => "Horarios", "value" => @booking.time.strftime("%I:%M %p el %d/%m/%Y") }] }.to_json
      @body["users"] = venues_objects
      make_request_venue
    end
end

def make_request_venue
  HTTParty.post("http://api.treble.ai/api/poll/49/deploy", headers: @header, body: @body)
end
```

Comment: It is hard to say what is the issue because we do not have access to the Treble API documentation. Can you please share it with us?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by `to_json` called in the wrong place.

The whole request body should be sent as a JSON. In your code, you call `to_json` for a hash that is later pushed into `@body["users"]` array.

Please remove `to_json` from `send_venue_notification` and call it for the `@body` when sending the request:

```
HTTParty.post("http://api.treble.ai/api/poll/49/deploy", headers: @headers, body: @body.to_json)
```